# Getting uninitialized value error in TCP code

Tags: c, tcp

I have a TCP code, but it keeps giving me error in the server code.

When I run it using valgrind, I get the following in my server terminal:

```
    ==12370== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==12370==    at 0x4E6B506: ____strtol_l_internal (in /lib64/libc-2.18.so)
==12370==    by 0x4E687DF: atoi (in /lib64/libc-2.18.so)
==12370==    by 0x400F1D: main (in /mnt/castor/seas_home/x/xyz/TCP/serv)
==12370== 
==12370== Invalid read of size 1
==12370==    at 0x4E6B506: ____strtol_l_internal (in /lib64/libc-2.18.so)
==12370==    by 0x4E687DF: atoi (in /lib64/libc-2.18.so)
==12370==    by 0x400F1D: main (in /mnt/castor/seas_home/a/xyz/TCP/serv)
==12370==  Address 0xffdfffac00000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12370== 
==12370== 
==12370== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==12370==  General Protection Fault
==12370==    at 0x4E6B506: ____strtol_l_internal (in /lib64/libc-2.18.so)
==12370==    by 0x4E687DF: atoi (in /lib64/libc-2.18.so)
==12370==    by 0x400F1D: main (in /mnt/castor/seas_home/a/xyz/TCP/serv)
==12370== 
==12370== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12370==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12370==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==12370== 
==12370== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12370== 
==12370== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12370== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==12370== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

But I can't figure out how to fix it. Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Line 133 of the server.c you posted is a blank line. If you're not going to post code *verbatim* to that which matches your valgind runs, mark the code with comments saying which line is which. And while you're at it, include `ctype.h` in your source file; its missing and all the `issomething()` functions are implicit declarations. Also, consider how the client or server knows the *length* of the strings being sent and takes appropriate steps to prepare for said data.

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited my question to have the exact code and the exact error message after running valgrind. Could you tell me the problem now?

Comment: Wimmel already hit the answer. You have indeterminate data and don't check your results.

Comment: a few suggestions: 1) compile with all warnings enabled, then fix the warnings,.  2) consistently indent the code, (I prefer an indent of 4 spaces).  Then, a warning in the client code, about the unused variable 'fromlen'. would have been obvious and easily corrected

Comment: this line: 'char buffer[1024]="";'  would be better written as: char buffer[1024]= {'\0'}; since that would have cleared the whole buffer array.

Comment: for the client, variable 'vote_count[50]' is set to the string "0" and never changed

Comment: in the client, after setting several fields to value in the buffer[] array, then this line is executed: 'memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));'  which sets all the bytes of the buffer[] array to '\0', probably not what is wanted

Comment: in the client, the comments say a datagram/UDP socket is being created, however that is not true.  I.E. when editing code, also edit the comments.

Comment: suggest, when displaying info about some system error, use the perror() function rather than the printf() function.  That is what the perror() function is for.

Comment: in the client, the variable 'i' is initialized to 0,  then in the 'while(i<1)' loop, i is incremented.  so the loop will only execute once.  is this the action wanted?  if so, why use a loop?

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers embedded in the code.  numbers like 100 and 50.  Such magic numbers make debug more difficult and greatly increase the probability of missed changes when performing maintenance.  suggest using #define for each of the magic numbers, so they only need to be updated in a single place.  When #defining numbers, the numbers should be surrounded by parens '(' and ')' to avoid  certain problems when the number is being used to replace the #define name in the code

Comment: The client function does not cleanly compile.  enable all compiler warnings so you are notified.  then fix the warnings. There are several warnings about implicit definitions of system functions (I.E. missing #include statement(s) )  There are several warnings about unused variables.  There are several warnings about variables being set but not used.

Comment: suggest commenting the code, so I/we (and you later on) do not have to reverse engineer the code to determine what is going on.

Comment: as a suggestion, when communicating between a server and a client, the server should not exit when there  is a communication error, but rather recover from the error. so it can handle the next connection request

Comment: the server can send several messages when it receives an 'option' of 2 (which is what the client is sending) however, the client, as currently coded, will miss all but the first reply message from the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is the important part of your code:

```
char *words[10];
char buffer[1024];
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
nwords = getwords(buffer, words, 10);
option = atoi(words[0]);
```

Because you call `getwords` with an empty buffer, it will return 0 and not set anything in `words`, so `words[0]` is also uninitialised.
You don't check the return value of `getwords`, but you should. If `nwords==0`, you should not use `words[0]`.

Comment: Then what could I do to fix this?

Comment: You know better what you are trying to do, so I can only give some general guidance. It looks like you expect `getwords` to return 7 words, so it if return less, you can't continue and should show an error message. Also, you need to fill the buffer before using it. I see some code commented out, is this on purpose, or did you forget to enable it again?

Comment: This statement above, which is commented out printf("MESSAGE CONTENTS: %.*s\n", (int)recsize, buffer); was there in the UDP code, here for TCP I don't understand how to fill the buffer, so commented that statement and put it at the end.

Comment: Split your problem into smaller tasks. And create a test program which does just that smaller task. If you need help, ask a new specific question for that task. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve So if you don't know how to communicate using TCP, you can remove everything related to the processing of the received data, as there is nothing to process until you are able to receive it.

Answer (score 0):

```
there are several basic problems with the server code.
here is just one that needs correction.

the server code is using the 'listen'/'accept' socket 
to write to the client.  
However, the accept function returns a NEW socket
That new socket is the one to use to communicate with the client.

here is an excerpt from the man page about the accept() function.

   The  accept()  system  call  is used with connection-based socket types
   (SOCK_STREAM,  SOCK_SEQPACKET).   It  extracts  the  first   connection
   request  on  the queue of pending connections for the listening socket,
   sockfd, creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file descrip‐
   tor  referring  to that socket.  The newly created socket is not in the
   listening state.  The original socket  sockfd  is  unaffected  by  this
   call.

   The  argument  sockfd is a socket that has been created with socket(2),
   bound to a local address with bind(2), and is listening for connections
   after a listen(2).
```

the key information is:

```
"creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file descrip‐
   tor  referring  to that socket."

suggest reading the manual 
for system functions that are called within your code
```

so the variable 'recsize' is actually a socket for communication with the client.